# Odoo v8: How to show tracks on event's detail page

Tags: odoo

I have created an event which features tracks. I have added a few tracks to the event and set them to "complete" in the kanban view, but how can I display them (e.g. in a breadcrumb part "Roster") on the event's detail page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - I had to restart Odoo, then it worked.